# mail style in html/div included in a safe way?

Tags: html, css

I have some php code that inserts a value into a div:

```
<div>".$update["textfielddata"]."</div>
```

Well, it works.. But if the textfielddata is an email filled with css/html... it f*cks up my "standard" css.

Is there a good way to isolate the email css/html so it still displays as intended within the "div" ?

Comment: Just the first thing that came to my mind: `iframe`? Not sure.

Comment: Read about iframe as a tool for this - and tried it.. without luck.

Comment: weird -  even if I use strip_tags on $update["textfielddata"] it acts weird.. will investigate further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tried to utilize html purify.. 
htmLawed saved the day: http://www.bioinformatics.org/phplabware/internal_utilities/htmLawed/

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$text = '<p>
    <style type="text/css">
P { margin-bottom: 0.21cm; direction: ltr; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); }P.western { font-family: "Times New Roman",serif; font-size: 12pt; }P.cjk { font-family: "Arial Unicode MS",sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; }P.ctl { font-family: "Tahoma"; font-size: 12pt; }    </style>
</p>
<p align="CENTER" class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0cm">
    <font size="5" style="font-size: 20pt"><u><b> TEXT I WANT TO GET </b></u></font></p>';

    $text=htmlentities($text);
echo $text;

?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately it does the "right" thing in securing the html. But it does not display the mail in other than clear text/code. Perhaps some html_purify() can assist me?